# Is it possible to extract the DOM version of a website into python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML I obtained by using `urllib.request.urlopen`, but I just cannot get the DOM version.

I have been searching the internet for solutions, but all I could find was the advise to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(rawHTML, 'html.parser')`.
Anyway, this does not get me the DOM code which I need to find a specific line (if it helps, I want to find images by using `soup.findAll('img')`.
I do have installed `lxml`

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

siteURL = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/"
rawHTML = urllib.request.urlopen(siteURL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(rawHTML, 'html.parser')

print(len(soup.findAll('img')))  # prints '0'
```

I hoped to get the actual number of images, but the output is 0.

I also tried `print(soup.text)`
and `print(soup.prettify)` and searched in those texts for "img", but it found nothing.

Comment: Because many sites (instagram included) are generated dynamically and asynchronously, you will likely have to use a browser automation tool like Selenium

Comment: But in the case of Instagram, you should use their API.